# Textview placed above ad (relativelayout) wont appear

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I try to put my textview above the ad and put them to the bottom of the page. I do this with

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" >

             <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adUnitId=""
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bAloha"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
                android:text="Aloha"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

But it is only showing me the ad and not the text.. any ideas?  Tried different things but never shows up..

Comment: in the textView, try using `android:id="@id/bAloha"`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where ads were not showing on 2.3.4 and below. The reason was that the dimension of the `AdView` is only known when the ad is effectively loaded. Since the AdView has a fixed and determined dimensions (e.g 320x50 px) you can set those dimensions to your `AdView`. So the `RelativeLayout` knows immediately where your `TextView` should be drawn

Comment: Thanks @Nathanz, however, I changed it to <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                ads:adUnitId=""
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/> but it is still not showing up.

Comment: Could that be that your background is white?

Comment: No... even by giving it a backgroundcolor it doesn't appear :s I might switch them to see if will change order.. just a sec